# I have truble with setTimeOut function

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I only started to learn jQuery, and i did my form where i have blur. My form send me inputs on email well, but blur doesn't removed after 2s how i made it. 
There is some code, can you say me where i made mistake? Thank you

```
 $(function () {
  $("form.callback").submit(function () { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../mail.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function () {
        $(th).find(".success").addClass("blur-active").css("display", "flex").hide().fadeIn();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(th).find("success").removeClass("blur-active").fadeOut();
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 2000);
    });
    return false;
});
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not finding the correct element inside the setTimeout. The dot "`.`" is missing to denote the class.

```
setTimeout(function () {
                $(th).find(".success").removeClass("blur-active").fadeOut();
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 2000);
```